# Gitlab as Docker won't start - no warnings, errors in the logs

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am a bit lost on this problem. I've been using Gitlab as Docker for some time now, but at some point it wouldn't boot up. All I get in the logs is this, with no errors or warnings:

```
Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!

Current version: gitlab-ce=15.8.0-ce.0

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file

And restart this container to reload settings.

To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab editor /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions

  docker restart gitlab

Cleaning stale PIDs & sockets

It seems you are upgrading from major version 14 to major version 15.

It is required to upgrade to the latest 15.0.x version first before proceeding.

Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version

Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!

Current version: gitlab-ce=15.8.0-ce.0

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file

And restart this container to reload settings.

To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab editor /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions

  docker restart gitlab

Cleaning stale PIDs & sockets

It seems you are upgrading from major version 14 to major version 15.

It is required to upgrade to the latest 15.0.x version first before proceeding.

Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version

Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!

Current version: gitlab-ce=15.8.0-ce.0

Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file

And restart this container to reload settings.

To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab editor /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions

  docker restart gitlab

Cleaning stale PIDs & sockets

It seems you are upgrading from major version 14 to major version 15.

It is required to upgrade to the latest 15.0.x version first before proceeding.

Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version
```

I tried to find other logs in the system with no luck. The recommended command to fix "update-permissions" didn't do the trick and I also started the container with sudo without success.

What can I try next?

Comment: It seems you are upgrading from major version 14 to major version 15.

It is required to upgrade to the latest 15.0.x version first before proceeding.

Please follow the upgrade documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrading-to-a-new-major-version

Comment: Don't forget to backup your data from that gitlab container, first migration could be messy.

Comment: If I understand that link right from @KamilCuk I have to follow a precise upgrade version jump procedure. But for that I have to know from which version I am coming and because this problem now lasts a long time, I don't know from which version I am originally coming from. So I'll guess I'll have to try some 14s versions. 
I just tried the last 14th, with no luck.

Comment: In the log I got this:
`Error executing action run on resource bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]` and this `Error executing action run on resource rails_migration[gitlab-rails]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a rollback to docker image [14.10.3-ce.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/gitlab/gitlab-ce/14.10.3-ce.0/images/sha256-1f769588d01e022fa94e5f8afd62d6b53f12a6719db4d0059c805ffd56e79015?context=explore). After that I got weird databse errors. So I did (on Debian 11):

1. login in docker container

```
docker exec -it gitlab_web_1 /bin/bash
```

2. excuted all following commands to migrate the database

```
rm /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postmaster.pid
```

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[ProjectNamespaces::BackfillProjectNamespaces,projects,id,'[null\,"up"]']
```

```
gitlab-rake db:migrate
```

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

```
apt dist-upgrade
```

```
gitlab-ctl restart
```

or as one command:

```
rm /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postmaster.pid ; gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[ProjectNamespaces::BackfillProjectNamespaces,projects,id,'[null\,"up"]'] && gitlab-rake db:migrate && gitlab-ctl reconfigure && apt dist-upgrade && gitlab-ctl restart
```

After that I could use my Gitlab again.